marking verts with custom attribute
Is it possible to select a bunch of edges and assign a custom attribute to the verts that those edges include, and then export that data in a GLTF?
I am aware that geometry nodes supports custom attributes but I can't find a way to assign based on a visual selection or to encode that as a custom attribute in GLTF.
The reason is that I want to parse the data in Bevy (game engine) to selectively render edges in a wireframe style. Meaning I select the edges I want to be visible in Blender, and construct line primitives from only the verts that have the custom attribute on the Bevy side.

Regarding setting custom Attributes for visually selected vertices/edges/faces in the 3D-viewport; That seems to be possible. In the Object Data Properties panel, in the Attributes Tab, you can add your own attributes. Be sure to have an attribute actively selected in the list to which you want to write data. Then, in Edit mode, select the vertices you want to set the attribute for, and use the F3 menu to search for Mesh > Set Attribute. You can then set a value for the selected geometry and the selected attribute type from the list.
However, glTF2.0 only seems to support attributes for vertices, sadly none for edges or faces. The Blender glTF-exporter furthermore only exports attributes which names start with an underscore (so: _attribute), and when you explicitly activate attribute exporting in the exporting menu under Data > Mesh > Attributes.
So, exporting edge data doesn't seem to be possible with the default glTF exporter.

thanks this is helpful. i can work with vertex attributes for sure.
